# TextOverflow.ellipsis not working even inside expanded

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, mobile-development

I have read dozens of stack overflow posts about `TextOverflow.ellipsis` not working, and pretty much every single one just said "Wrap it in an Expanded widget"

That is not working. I have tried putting the Expanded widget around the Text widget, the Row Widget, the Container Widget...nothing is working. As soon as I add the Expanded Widget, I get an error because there is already an Expanded Widget for the

PLEASE HELP. I'm gonna lose my mind. The only "solution" I've found is to do a set width on a Container right around the Text Widget, which is not what I want since I want the Text Container to be flexible to the screen size.

Error:

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#96e5e relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Code:

```
Expanded(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_centeredPadding, _paddingTop, 0, 24),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: center ? MainAxisAlignment.center : MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: size == 'mobile' ? CrossAxisAlignment.start : CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                    child: Image(
                      width: _iconSize,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/users/user-3.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Really long name does not fit',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: textStyle,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 16),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home/settings');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And just to reiterate, this is not the solution:

```
Expanded(
  child: Text(
    'Really long name does not fit',
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    style: textStyle,
  ),
),
```

[Picture of the non-working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAajw.png)

[What I wish it looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4AzU.png)

Comment: What is the parent of your ```Expanded``` widget? If it is not a ```Row``` or ```Column```, try wrapping it with one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a problem with wrong widget nesting (Row, in Row, in Row)...

Here's a simplified example of the result you're trying to achieve using only one Row.

Adjust it to your needs.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomHeader({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Really long name does not fit' * 3, // Yes, you can multiply strings in dart :)
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Icon(Icons.settings),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              color: Colors.cyan[700],
            ),
            child: Text(
              'Give',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does seem to be the problem, thank you! How would I go about safely putting a Row inside another Row? I need to pass this Row Widget into another, but even inside a container it doesn't work. I feel like there has to be a way to easily cut off text, but also build a layout with some nested Rows...

Comment: @HD_ it's a bit strange that you need a Row in Row. But if you still need to use it that way, just be sure that the inner Row is wrapped with Expanded.